# Selectors in jquery problems

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, this

My problem is quite simple. What I want to do in jquery is something like this:

```
$(this > ".otherDiv").show();
```

But it doesn't work and I have no idea why. I also tried:

```
$(this).$(".otherDiv").show();
$(this + ".otherDiv").show();
$(this ".otherDiv").show();
$(this.".otherDiv").show();
```

It works when I replace this with something else. And I tested and this is really the parent div I want. Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct form:

```
$(this).children('.otherDiv').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find(".otherDiv").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not a jquery object, it is a Javascript one. Try something like this:

```
$(this).find('.otherDiv').show ();
```

Answer (score 1):

My personal favourite is:

```
$(".otherDiv", this).show();
```

Which is an elegent, shorthand way of writing:

```
$(this).find('.otherDiv').show ();
```

Hope that helps :)